# Ubuntu 20.04 - Port forwarding with iptables causing "temporary failure in name resolution" when using sudo

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables, port-forwarding

I'm working on a project where my Ubuntu machine port forwards external connections to a second computer on LAN running a game server. I found a few tutorials online on how to do this and  ended up using [this one](https://my.esecuredata.com/index.php?/knowledgebase/article/49/how-to-redirect-an-incoming-connection-to-a-different-ip-address-on-a-specific-port-using-iptables/) which worked great and successfully port-forwarded except it also made connecting to the machine almost impossible as (although I could successfully connect via ssh and execute commands) every time I used sudo, the terminal stopped for about 10-20 seconds before continuing and gave the error:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host devonServer: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

What I found strange is that it never disconnected me from the machine or prevented me from logging in, it just had a delay and error message every time I used sudo.

I spent some time troubleshooting and found that the command `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE` was responsible for the problem but I was unsuccessful at finding a different solution which didn't include that line or a way to fix the error I was recieving.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `devonServer` cannot be resolved. If that's the name of the local host, check that it appears in `/etc/hosts` (or add it if it's not there) in a line like:

```
127.0.0.1 devonServer
```